# Problem installing SQLite3 RubyGem on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sqlite

I am having a problem trying to install the SQLite3 RubyGem. Here's what I'm  doing:

```
$ sudo gem install --remote sqlite3-ruby
```

Here's the output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for fdatasync() in -lrt... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --with-rtlib
    --without-rtlib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out
```

Comment: can you post the contents of `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out`

Comment: the contents of that file ended up being exactly the same as what I originally posted

Comment: is there a `mkmf.log` file in the same directory?

Answer (score 3):

Here's your answer:

> http://kristofhouwen.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/install-sqlite3-ruby-gem-on-ubuntu-810/

First I install the Sqlite3 database:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

After this we install the lib so we don’t get the error:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Now we can install the gem without the error:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

The first command (installing sqlite3) may not be necessary.

Comment: Worked for raspberry pi as well.